# Using Laravel Passport with a Load Balancer

Tags: laravel, oauth, laravel-5.4, laravel-passport

In my Laravel app, I'm using Passport's Password Grant to give API access to an iOS application.

In my production environment, I'm also using one load balancer to distribute requests to two servers. All have been created in forge.

I can use the Password Grant token to authenticate a user via iOS, and have the API return the bearer access_token. However, the load balancer then ships the next request to the other server, which seems not to recognize the access_token, and so throws a 401.

Question #1: Does anyone have experience using Passport with a load-balanced environment? If so, did you run into this issue?

Question #2: Where is the access_token stored? I see it referenced within my database via an ID, but the token itself isn't stored there. Without, I'm not sure how to persist from server to server.

Comment: What session driver are you using? Does all servers have the same APP_KEY?

Comment: Hi Cameron, how did you eventually solve this? Were your oauth-private.key and oauth-public.key files the same on all of the application servers that the LB is balancing traffic between? I seemed to be getting the same behavior that you describe in the question, but after ensuring that all application servers are using the same key pair, it seems to be working (not sure if this is the correct solution though).

Comment: Hi Cameron, is this solved for you? I am running in the same issue and as @ChristianF suggested the keys are identical but it's still not working.

Comment: @shaile are you getting 401s depending on which application server the LB forwards the request to? I have this working in production now so I might be able to assist.

Comment: Thanks @ChristianF no I am not getting any 401, can this be related with the ports 80 or 443 the instances are listening to?

Comment: @ChristianF I have this issue now, and the passport keys are the same on all servers but if the request is processed by any server that did not initiate the token i have a 401 error.

Comment: Not sure why tho

Answer (score 0):

Although there are multiple ways to solve this issue, most are messy (e.g. having the client add the token as a request param to subsequent requests, etc.) . I think the best and cleanest solution would be to use [sticky sessions](https://www.nginx.com/products/session-persistence/) on [Forge](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/forge/sticky-sessions-on-laravel-forge-load-balancer)

Comment: as far as i know, sticky session will force a device to keep requesting to the same server for an amount of days(max 7), after 7 days if the request is passed to another server an authorization error will be thrown, this is not always the cleanest way. 
the cleanest way is to let the servers use the same passport keys to validate the tokens. specially that there is not session.